# How to fill the value the same as key in translation.json i18next-parser

Tags: i18next, i18next-http-backend

I use **i18next-parser** to parse my tsx code but i cannot find the proper configuration argument, i want to fill the value the same string as key is in generated translation.json. It mean that the default values must be the same the key it-self.

I expect use the text string as the keys and as a value, so i found the default config on i18next-parser github but there is no clear explanation what use as default value.

Currently my generated *translation.json*

```
{
  "Hello world header!": ""
}
```

but i need it like this:

```
{
  "Hello world header!": "Hello world header!"
}
```

Here is my *i18next-parser.config.ts* almost default config

```
export default {
  contextSeparator: '::',// <---- this was customized by me
  defaultValue: '',
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: the **defaultValue** maybe a function so it receives the key and get and return the value using *regex* and my **contextSeparator** which is set to `contextSeparator: '::'` in *i18next-parser.config.ts (see in the question)*. So dont forget to replace `::` to your `contextSeparator`

I configured it like this

```
export default {
  contextSeparator: '::',// <---- this was customized by me
  defaultValue: (locale: string, namespace: string, key: string) =>
    key.match(/^(.*(?=::\w*)|.*(?!::\w*))/g)?.[0],,
  ...
};
```